# directives and scope @

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm learning the "scope" option in angularjs directives and couldnt figure out why the @ isnt working. YOu can check the code http://jsfiddle.net/gerlstar/Lzgts/. The issue is that the second h4 tag is suppose to display "I'm a directive, within the app .. " but it is displaying "Hello world". Any help would be great thanks.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-init="title = 'Hello World'">
     <h2 id="appTitle">{{title}}</h2>

    <button id="newAppTitle" ng-click="setAppTitle('App 2.0')">Upgrade me!</button>
    <div my-scoped-directive msd-title="I'm a directive, within the app {{title}}">
         <h4 id="directiveTitle">{{title}}</h4>

        <button id="newDirTitle" ng-click="setDirectiveTitle('bob')">Bob it!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('mainModule', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.setAppTitle = function (title) {
        $scope.title = title;
    };
});


app.directive('myScopedDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            'title': '@msdTitle'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.setDirectiveTitle = function (title) {
                $scope.title = title;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I removed attribute 'ng-transclude' from the template here http://jsfiddle.net/2cAYt/7/ if that points you in the right direction.

Comment: @gerl Bad fiddle, isn't it?